# Why is Kernel#require taking such a big chunk of my application's resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, profiling

I am trying out ruby-prof and ran it against a somewhat self-contained module.  The core of the module is 3 classes, with maybe 3 other helper classes being used.  So there shouldn't be a huge amount of overhead with tons of requires and incluces.  Is this normal in a big(gish) app with a fair number of gems installed?

```
 18.06      7.67     1.99     0.00     7.66     1366  Kernel#require
  5.80      1.21     0.64     0.00     0.83    18704  Array#map
  5.73     10.21     0.63     0.00    10.09    38133  Array#each
  5.17      1.13     0.57     0.00     0.56    21796  Array#include?
  4.40      0.49     0.49     0.00     0.00   345434  Symbol#to_s
  3.78      0.42     0.42     0.00     0.00   446478  String#==
```

Comment: A fair number of gems?  Can you elaborate?  Seems like that would likely account for the require time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `ruby-prof`'s [documentation](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/):

> To profile a Rails application it is
>   vital to run it using production like
>   settings (cache classes, cache view
>   lookups, etc.). Otherwise, Rail’s
>   dependency loading code will overwhelm
>   any time spent in the application
>   itself (our tests show that Rails
>   dependency loading causes a roughly 6x
>   slowdown).

Are you running this using production settings?  If you aren't using cached data and instead have to read the files/classes from disk every time, I can understand why you are seeing your system spend so much time in `Kernel#require`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran ruby-prof on a similar case, according to your description, except that mine only requires two gems, which I wouldn't consider qualifies as 'a fair number'.  That being said, I still spent 10% of my 7 second run time with the Kernel#gem_original_require class.

I imagine that what you are seeing is pretty typical, as it seems to be comparable to my case.